# gdb not printing string value correctly

Tags: c, gdb, pthreads

I have a multithreaded (pthreads) program in which *main()* calls a function omp_file_open_all() and passes in a string as *char** alongwith other arguments. I was debugging something using gdb and saw that gdb does not print out the string value correctly, whereas a printf inside the function prints it out correcly.

```
Breakpoint 1, omp_file_open_all (fd=0x423bb950, filename=0x7f605df078e0 "", mode=-16843009) at pthread_coll_file_open.c:29
29          if(omp_get_thread_num() == MASTER)
(gdb) print filename
$1 = 0x7f605df078e0 ""
```

So gdb shows *filename* as empty, whereas a printf inside the function outputs the correct value as "/tmp/test.out". The function being called (omp_file_open_all) is defined as follows (not in the same file as *main()*):
*`int omp_file_open_all (int fd, char* filename, int mode);`*

I cant post my program here as this is a part of a larger code thats approx. 1500 lines of code. 'filename' is a global variable and is set in main() by the main thread before newer threads are spawned.

So this is not an error, and I merely stumbled across it, but I am interested in finding out why gdb does not display the correct value.

OS: 64bit OpenSUSE,
gdb 6.8

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Nobody wants you to post your entire 1.5KLOC program; make a testcase!

Comment: `0x7f605df078e0` is a very suspicious pointer value. Without any code we cannot tell why.

Comment: Do you compile differently when you test with `printf` and with gdb? Maybe the compiler is optimizing the filename out ...

Comment: @pmg, I dont test separately using printf and gdb. The printf is always present.

Comment: @Tomalak, I tried stripping down the 1.5KLOC code, and I cant reproduce the above scenario. I wrote similar, separate test cases, and I dont see the above behaviour. gdb shows the filename correctly. And forgive me for not saying this before, but the above code is a pthreads code.

Answer (score 0):

There might be some thing going wrong in your code. With the following code snippet, I am getting the string printed by **gdb** correctly.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void checkString( char* fileName )
{
    printf("%s", fileName);
}

int main()
{
    char* name = "temp";
    checkString(name);

    return 0;
}


mahesh-babu-vattiguntas-macbook-pro:Desktop mahesh$ gdb gdb.out
GNU gdb 6.3.50-20050815 (Apple version gdb-1469) (Wed May  5 04:36:56 UTC 2010)
Copyright 2004 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
GDB is free software, covered by the GNU General Public License, and you are
welcome to change it and/or distribute copies of it under certain conditions.
Type "show copying" to see the conditions.
There is absolutely no warranty for GDB.  Type "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "x86_64-apple-darwin"...Reading symbols for shared libraries .. done

(gdb) b gdb.c:6
Breakpoint 1 at 0x100000ebc: file gdb.c, line 6.
(gdb) run gdb.out
Starting program: /Users/mahesh/Desktop/gdb.out gdb.out
Reading symbols for shared libraries +. done

Breakpoint 1, checkString (fileName=0x100000f05 "temp") at gdb.c:6
6       printf("%s", fileName);
(gdb) p fileName
$1 = 0x100000f05 "temp"
(gdb)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try stepping forward one line (gdb "s" command) after you hit the breakpoint, then try printing it again. I've sometimes seen gdb have trouble displaying parameter values correctly when breaking at the beginning of a function.

Answer (score 0):

My first guess was that there is a scoping issue, since the name of the function parameter and your global variable is identical. However, this does not seem to be the case for the following very small program:

```
#include <cstdio>

static char const* filename = "something";

int foobar(char const* filename)
{
  printf("%s\n", filename);
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  return foobar("somethingelse");
}
```

Compiled with:

```
g++ -ggdb -g3 -O0    test.cpp   -o test
```

GDB (7.2, also on x64 but Ubuntu) gives:

```
Breakpoint 1, foobar (filename=0x400706 "somethingelse") at test.cpp:7
7         printf("%s\n", filename);
(gdb) p filename
$1 = 0x400706 "somethingelse"
```

So it's not about scoping per-se. Also, the output suggests that the parameter is indeed an empty string at execution time. Could you please provide us with the output of `bt` at the same time you break into the debugger? Last two stack frames are sufficient.

Comment: @Kshitij_Mehta: sorry, can't see anything. Can you edit it into your original question? Or did you mean to say there is no output?

Comment: Heres the output of bt:
(gdb) bt
#0  omp_file_open_all (fd=0x41d90950, filename=0x7fe348e858e0 "", mode=1223186656) at pthread_coll_file_open.c:46


#1  0x0000000000401a81 in pthread_task (_tid=1) at main.c:177


#2  0x00000000004019ca in pthread_start_routine (threadid=0x60a100) at main.c:155


#3  0x00007fe348e7c040 in start_thread () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0


#4  0x00007fe348bef0cd in clone () from /lib64/libc.so.6

Comment: The filename is different if I run just one thread. Heres the output of gdb:'Breakpoint 1, omp_file_open_all (fd=0x405b70, filename=0x401520 "1▒I\211▒^H\211▒H\203▒▒PTI▒▒`[@", mode=1701996660) at pthread_coll_file_open.c:29
29          if(omp_get_thread_num() == MASTER)
(gdb) p filename
$1 = 0x401520 "1▒I\211▒^H\211▒H\203▒▒PTI▒▒`[@" '
For threads>1, the filename for the non-master threads is empty

Comment: Is it possible that one of the threads is tampering with the global filename value? What storage type do you use for filename? Since you use OMP, have you made sure all threads have access to the same resource or will they ultimately get a different copy? ...

Comment: filename was read from a config file as follows: '(fgets(buffer, MAXLINE, Conf_File);  strncpy(tmpfilename, &buffer[i], MAXLINE-i); filename = tmpfilename;' (just showing important snippets of code). Plus, i dont really use openmp, this library replicates some openmp functions, it is pretty much a pthreads library

Comment: Well, what's odd is the fact that in your original question `omp_file_open_all (fd=0x423bb950, filename=0x7f605df078e0 ""` the parameter `filename` passed to omp_file_open_all is an empty string, while here in ´bt` (which should be identical) it is ` omp_file_open_all (fd=0x405b70, filename=0x401520 "1▒I\211▒^H\211▒H\203▒▒PTI▒▒[@"` ...

Comment: Filename is empty for all threads except the main thread where it is 1▒I\211▒^H\211▒H\203▒▒PTI▒▒[@. I just saw this behaviour when I was running more tests.

Comment: Okay, that's got to be it then, right? Check the context of the thread which breaks into the debugger. Looks like when you see the behavior that prompted you to your question, you are not within the context of the "main" thread.

Comment: Well that doesnt seem to work either. (Sorry for the late reply)